# Make a link out of a <figure>

Tags: popup, hover

How can I make a link out of [THIS PROJECT](http://cssdeck.com/labs/mit1lbwj)?
And by link, I mean I wanna be able to click on the picture in order to open a popup box.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick

```
<div class="grid">
                    <figure class="effect-apollo">
                        <a class="modal-button" data-content="ef">
                            <img  src="#">
                            <figcaption>
                                <h2>Strong <span></span></h2>
                                <p></p>
                            </figcaption>   
                        </a>        
                    </figure>
                </div>
```